# Integrate pytest inside python app (provide fixture)

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I want to use pytest to execute tests, as part of my application (which run specific tests according to own logic).

I want to provide those tests with fixtures. They (those fixtures) should have access to internals of my application, so 'pytest.main()' is not an option.

How can I integrate pytest as library for my application? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've asked for this in pytest issue tracker. Short version:

1. create fixture with `@pytest.fixture`
2. Create class, containing this fixture
3. Create instance of that class
4. Pass it as `pytest.main([args], plugins=[instance_of_class])`

Longer answer: https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/passing-fixtures-to-test-in-pytest-e8dade1f01ff#.mcedmivel